# Display Maxmind Geoip2 Display Country, City, Region and ISP with Javascript

Tags: javascript, maxmind

I currently use the legacy maxmind geoip service to display country, city and region the user is visiting from. I would like to use the geoip2 service to display the information but it is beyond my skill level.

Here is the javascript I am currently using to display the data using the legacy version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.liquidvpn.com/global/ip.php"></script>
<br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//j.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//j.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js">
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         document.write( "Country: "+geoip_country_name()+"<br />" );
         document.write( "Region: "+geoip_region_name()+"<br />" );
        document.write( "City: "+geoip_city()+"<br />" );
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do the same thing with the geoip2 version and add the ISP, IP and if they are using an open proxy? I am subscribed to their service already (not trying to do this on the free service)

Comment: Have you tried following [this tutorial](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/#Put_the_Users_City_Name_in_a_Page)?

Comment: Yes but even that is beyond my skill level. The legacy stuff was so easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will behave similarly to the code you posted. It uses jQuery but you could rewrite it without.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//j.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js"></script>

<script>
geoip2.cityISPOrg(function (response) {
    $("#country").html(response.country.names.en);
    $("#region").html(response.most_specific_subdivision.names.en);
    $("#city").html(response.city.names.en);
    $("#isp").html(response.traits.isp);
    $("#proxy").html(response.traits.is_anonymous_proxy);
    $("#ip").html(response.traits.ip_address);
}, null, { w3cGeolocationDisabled: true });
</script>

<p>
    <span id="country"></span>,
    <span id="region"></span>,
    <span id="city"></span>,
    <span id="isp"></span>,
    <span id="ip"></span>,
    is proxy? <span id="proxy"></span>
</p>
```

All of the fields in the response object are outlined on the [MaxMind dev site](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/#Response_Body).

Comment: Hi thanks. That prints what I have currently. I thought I would be able to add more to it but it doesnt seem to work. I would like to add the ISP, IP and if a proxy is detected. Could you tell me how this is done?

Comment: I added the other fields. The response object has the same structure as [this object](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/#Output_Examples). You should be able to use any fields supported by the endpoint you are using.

Comment: That works great but the spans break the rest of my page for some reason. I have it on a wordpress widget. Could I call that from another document perhaps?

Comment: I have done some research and for whatever reason that script creates javascript errors on my site. They are a n</br>    TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined [js/jquery.isotope.min.js:11]
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' [/js/main.js:322]

Comment: Guys the links above are wrong?? j.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js should be js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js, note the missing 's'. I can't make a one letter edit.

Comment: Alos, can anyone tell me if this is free? It does not appear to be: https://dev.maxmind.com/release-note/free-javascript-service-discontinued/?

Comment: MaxMind no longer has a free JavaScript service. You could try https://freegeoip.net/ if you are looking for a free service.